# RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars- Y[i]=sum(V[:,i])/float(a)

Tags: python, runtime-error

So my friend and I are working on a project (I am kind of a beginner).

I am working on IDLE on Mac and she is working on `spyder` windows 7.

For some reason, this code works on her computer but not on mine. I am not sure why I keep getting this same `runtime` warning.

Maybe the file is too large? not sure. I read other answers on here for this same problem but didn't find anything that worked from the suggestions.

I feel it might be something that is common sense but I am overlooking.

Thank you so much

```
dates = [line.split(",")[3] for line in lines[1:]] #first i extract the dates.
dates = [[int(i) for i in date.split("/")] for date in dates] #then i split the month,day and year.
X = np.arange(1,13,dtype="float") #the months from 1 to 12.
V = np.zeros(48).reshape(4,12)
for date in dates :
    V[date[2]-2014,date[0]-1] += 1 
Y = np.zeros(12) #the array holding the average of violations for every month.
a = 0
for i in range(12):
    #a = 0 #i added this variable because some months data are missing so i only divied by the number of year where there is a record.
    for j in range(4):
        if V[j,i] != 0.0 :
            a = a + 1
    Y[i]=sum(V[:,i])/float(a)
def f(x): #this is he fitted function.
    return np.polyfit(X,Y,1)[0]*x+np.polyfit(X,Y,1)[1]
```

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"?

Comment: it gives me an error, the runtime warning above

Comment: A warning is not an error. Is there a discernible difference in *output*? Have you tried putting some debugging prints to see what might be causing the warning?